# PHP Mailer exception "u must provide email adress.."

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm getting an wired exception while using phpmailer v5.1

> Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'You must provide at least one recipient email address.

I checked if i have a correct Email in there

```
    $oMail->AddReplyTo = FROM;
    $oMail->AddAddress = "testmail@web.de";
    $oMail->SetFrom = FROM;
```

but still the same exception. any ideas what the problem can be?

Comment: `FROM` doesn't seem to be a valid email address..

Comment: what does FROM have, can you post that as well..

Comment: define("FROM", "myemail@internaldb.de");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddAddress` is a method, not a property. So, it should be like

`$oMail->AddAddress("testmail@web.de");`

This applies to all three settings you're trying to apply.

Comment: awesome.  thx a lot. I should have read the manual more accurate.  thx for your fast help